# $90$ Degree Piping Cuts on Cylinders

Tags: geometry, solid-geometry

I'm trying to find the math behind laying out piping cuts. For instance, when one piece of pipe tees (at $90$ degrees) into another piece of pipe, how do you cut the pipe? I'm trying to figure out the math of creating a flat template that I can wrap around a pipe to draw a line and then cut the pattern with a torch for both parts when intersecting.

How do you draw the pattern when it's not a $90$, but a $45$, $30$, and $60$ degree tee.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make a $ 90^{\circ}$ bend one needs to cut the tube at half the angle i.e., $45^{\circ}.$ For an $L$ full section and for Tee half section.

An intersection of a pipe and plane is an ellipse. The *development* of a pipe dia $D$ cut by a plane making angle $\alpha$ to diametral plane is always a cosine curve.

That is when thin flexible truncated  pipe is laid flat, an ellipse boundary assumes the shape of a cosine curve.

This is the development of a sectioned or [truncated cylinder](https://etc.usf.edu/clipart/42500/42568/truncyl_42568.htm) . The development curve is to be drawn on paper to make the template. Length is $\pi D$ and the cosine wave height is $D\tan \alpha$. The paper is wrapped around the tube, keeping that as guide to hand-saw at angle $\alpha$ with a hacksaw.

[Powered mitre saws](https://www.boschhardware.com/store/product/bosch-sliding-mitre-saw-gcm-8-sjl/) are for larger production volumes.  Any desired angle can be mitred. You only need to clamp the tube at  desired $\alpha$ and lower the running saw.